# Sort experience on Stack Overflow Careers by date descending

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

Stack Overflow Careers should sort experience by the date(s) of the experience and not by when it was entered.

I am going to have to delete several old options from my profile because they are old and not the most relevant.

Answer (score 3):

On the profile edit view we have these buttons to let you move sections around at will.

> [image]